# Compare the same field on the same table for the same stock code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Table:

```
StockCode     Bin
123           L02A3
123           L08B2
123           L08C2
456           L04B2
456           L02C1
789           L19A2
```

When looking at a Bin for a stock code, any bin that contains an "A" is on the floor level of the warehouse.  If the bin contains a "B", it is on the middle rack of the warehouse, and if the bin contains a "C", it is on the top rack of the warehouse.

I would like a sql query that compares all the bins for each stock code and shows which stock codes do not have a current bin on the "A" level.

From the example table above, stock code "456" would show because it is the only stock code that does not have inventory in an "A" bin.

This will be very helpful because it will flag us to which inventory to move down to the floor level before the pick tickets are printed.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think `group by` and `having`:

```
select stockcode
from t
group by stockcode
having sum(case when bin like '%A_' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows for each stock code where the bin has an A (this assumes that the penultimate letter is an A, as in the examples in the question).  If the number is `0`, then the stock code is returned.

Comment: Thank you! @Gordon Linoff for steering me in the right direction.  This worked exactly as I was hoping.